# is there a way to skip to the next song after it has been playing for 30 seconds using the spotify API

Tags: javascript, spotify

is there a way using the [spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/) to skip to next song after a certain time has passed in the song playing?

I cant seem to find any documentation where you can pull the time the song has been playing.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The player has the `position` property (the documentation is broken) that will give you the current playback position in milliseconds.

Observing the player object for `EVENT.CHANGE` you can see when the track has started/stopped played, and you can time appropriately.

Comment: since the documentation is broken do you know another source that might have full documentation?